# returning strings instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function (onlyOddNumbers) that accepts an array of numbers and returns a new array with only the odd numbers, it's working but the problem is I'm getting strings in the new array instead of numbers, why this happen ?

[image]

```
let oddNumbersOnly=[]
const filter = function (numbers) {
  for (number in numbers){
    if(number %2 !==0){
      oddNumbersOnly.push(number)
    }
  } return oddNumbersOnly;
};
```

Comment: Maybe use this  `oddNumbersOnly.push(+number)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use for of instead of for in then convert your num to string

```js
const filter = function(numbers) {
  let oddNumbersOnly = []
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (number % 2 !== 0) {
      oddNumbersOnly.push(number.toString())
    }
  }
  return oddNumbersOnly;
};
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const result = filter(arr)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It seems, @AlaaKhalila wants to get numbers: "...the problem is I'm getting strings in the new array instead of numbers".

Comment: problem solved , I just used ( for of ) instead of ( for in )

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let oddNumbersOnly = num.filter(numb=>numb%2 !==0);
console.log(oddNumbersOnly);
```

javaScript has an inbuilt es6 filter function. It is shorter and retain the datatype. You may try this.